# PHP QuickBooks Desktop Customer Query

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have been using `[quickbooks-php][1]`  library by the `Consolibyte`. I wanted to log in the Customer Query Result in a file named `CustomerQuery.txt` but the messages I am getting as follows-

```
Version:
Not provided by service

Message:
No data exchange required

Description:
No data to exchange for this application. Job ending.
```

and here is the PHP code-

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    require_once('config.php');
    require_once($QuickBooksFile);

    if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    }

    $map = array(
        QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_query_request', '_quickbooks_customer_query_response' ),
    );

    $errmap = array();
    $hooks = array();
    $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;
    $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;
    $soap_options = array();
    $handler_options = array(
        'authenticate' => '_quickbooks_custom_auth', 
        'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
    );

    if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($DSN))
    {
        QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($DSN);
        QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($DSN, $user, $pass);
        $primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;
        $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($DSN);
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
    }

    $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($DSN, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soap, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options);
    $response = $Server->handle(true, true);

    function _quickbooks_custom_auth($Username, $Password, &$QuickBooksCompanyFile){
        return true;
    }

    function _quickbooks_customer_query_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                    <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                            <CustomerQueryRq requestID="1">
                                <FullName>Kaley Baker</FullName>
                                <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                            </CustomerQueryRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';
        return $xml;
    }

    function _quickbooks_customer_query_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {
        file_put_contents('CustomerQuery.txt', $xml);
    }
```

The `config.php` file contents are as follows-

```
    $UserName='Admin';
    $Password='Test123';
    $DSN='mysqli://root@localhost/qb';
    $QuickBooksCompanyFile = 'E:\QB.QBW';
    $QuickBooksFile='C:\xampp\htdocs\accounting\qb\QuickBooks.php';
    $Email='demo.code@gmail.com';
    $DBHost='localhost';
    $DBUser='root';
    $DBPass='';
    $DBName='qb'; 
    */
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google or StackOverflow search yields the following link (together with a sea of other posts saying the same thing):

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_-_No_data_exchange_required

Which says:

> What does "No data exchange required" mean?
>
> That message means exactly what it says:
>
> There's no data to exchange. There's nothing to do. The Web Connector
>   (and most frameworks/dev kits built around it) use a 'queue' concept.
>   Once the queue is empty, there's nothing else to do, and you'll get
>   that message. If you add something to the queue, then it will process
>   those items until there's nothing left to do, and then you'll get the
>   "No Data Exchange..." message again.
>
> So, for instance, say you want to build a process whereby every time a
>   customer is created within your store, the customer gets created in
>   QuickBooks. You'd then want to set up a process where when that
>   customer is created within your store, you queue up a request to add
>   the customer to QuickBooks.

Looking at your code, there is only one call to any sort of `queue` method:

> $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);

And if you go back to the docs/examples where you found this code:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php#L288

From this library:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

You'll see the big comment that says:

```
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: This particular example of queueing something up will 
    //  only ever happen *once* when these scripts are first run/used. After 
    //  this initial test, you MUST do your queueing in another script. DO NOT 
    //  DO YOUR OWN QUEUEING IN THIS FILE! See 
    //  docs/example_web_connector_queueing.php for more details and examples 
    //  of queueing things up.
```

Sooooo...

- Have you queued anything up that needs to be processed? Doesn't look like it.
- If you have, where's the code for that? What do the database records (stored in the `quickbooks_queue` SQL table) look like?
- Go queue something up, and you won't get this message anymore.
- Need to know how to queue up something? Refer to the example that the code links you to:

Example:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_queueing.php